# Collect file list from folder or mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-5

**Which one is faster and use less resource for larger file list?**

1) Collect list of files and folder path from mysql database for JSON

2) Directly access the folder / file list then create JSON data accordingly

Answer (score 1):

File operations have a high cost and databases have optimised read, especially if you use indexes as well.

However, whether the general description applies to your specific case depends on a lot of things, like will you need to read subfolders? Do you have some custom logic to parse? You will need to answer yourself these answers, but on general note it is better to store your folder paths and file paths in your database. Depends on their size as well. And also on the place where your database is located (on the same computer as the application server, or remotely).

Comment: Main folder already has over 20k files and subfolders. It would be 3/4 line code to link them to json by direct access. As for database call, I have to implement code to create access link during file upload. And for current large file list, have to create anotherauto  script for migration. Therefore I need to make sure which one is the best choice before I start.

Comment: @Fresco that's not a very large number for a database, I think you could choose the database approach and use batches if the number is too large for a single query, like batches of 1000.